# pfctl config to only allow OpenVPN connection

Tags: macos, vpn, firewall

I found what appears to be a suitable guide [here](https://zorrovpn.com/articles/osx-pf-vpn-only?lang=en), but pfctl complains of a syntax error and "no IP address found for en3" which is my main interface. I have had other pf rules working successfully to forward ports, etc. but I cannot figure this out.

I am on 10.11.4 and using Tunnelblick connected to a OpenVPN server i installed myself on a VPS.

Could someone give instructions on the correct configuration for pfctl on El Capitan? I need to keep open access to private networks like 10.0.0.0 and 168.1.0.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works on Sierra.

Append the following lines to the end of /etc/pf.conf

```
anchor "org.vpnonly.pf"
load anchor "org.vpnonly.pf" from "/etc/pf.anchors/org.vpnonly.pf.rules"
```

Create this configuration file at /etc/pf.anchors/org.vpnonly.pf.rules

```
# Options
set block-policy drop
set fingerprints "/etc/pf.os"
set ruleset-optimization basic
set skip on lo0

# Interfaces
vpn_intf = "{ utun0 utun1 utun2 utun3 }"

# Ports
allowed_vpn_ports = "{ 1:65535 }"

# Table with allowed IPs
table <allowed_vpn_ips> persist file "/etc/pf.anchors/vpn.list" file "/etc/pf.anchors/custom.list"

# Block all outgoing packets
block out all

# Antispoof protection
#had to disable this to avoid error
#antispoof for $vpn_intf inet

# Allow outgoing packets to specified IPs only
pass out proto icmp from any to <allowed_vpn_ips>
pass out proto {tcp udp} from any to <allowed_vpn_ips> port $allowed_vpn_ports

# Allow traffic for VPN interfaces
pass out on $vpn_intf all
```

Create /etc/pf.anchors/vpn.list and /etc/pf.anchors/custom.list

`sudo touch /etc/pf.anchors/vpn.list /etc/pf.anchors/custom.list`

Add a list of allowed IP addresses (addresses of VPN servers) to /etc/pf.anchors/vpn.list

```
41.xxx.xxx.xxx
42.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Add google DNS to custom /etc/pf.anchors/custom.list
    8.8.8.8
    8.8.4.4

`sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf` and check for errors

To load at startup, edit to default pfctl at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist` to set
`<key>Disabled</key>`
`<true/>`

ensure rootless mode is disabled. (boot to recovery terminal with <kbd>Command+R</kbd> at the chime and run `csrutil disable` run these commands, then return to recovery terminal afterwards to reenable rootless with `csrutil enable`

Create your LaunchDaemon at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.apple.pfctl</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>pfctl</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>-f</string>
        <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

finish with `sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist`, reboot with rootless mode enabled and you're set.

Comment: I always wanted to answer this question - I have an open tab with this question for 2 months now - but failed to setup a properly working OpenVPN server at AWS. Good to see that it is answered now.

Comment: Do you really have to edit `/etc/pf.conf` as root? this seems so broken. In linux/windows you can just add new firewalls rules by calling `iptables` or `wfp` code -- is there really no way to do this in osx without editing a frikkin config file as root?

Comment: the file is owned by root: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1.0K 16 Jul  2017 /etc/pf.conf`
it may be possible to create a user owned config file as well. i have not tried.