# pfctl config to allow VPN host names instead of IP addresses in OpenVPN connection

Tags: network, vpn, dns, firewall

I would like to use VPN domain names instead of IP addresses to only allow some VPN servers on my Mac. I did everything [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235875/pfctl-config-to-only-allow-openvpn-connection) to set up pfctl to only allow some VPN servers to open access to some specific IP addresses however, I don't know how to add host names instead IP addresses to my allowed VPN list.

Because the IP addresses changes but host names not, is it possible to add host names instead IP addresses to pfctl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the host names instead of IPs to the tables. If DNS resolution isn't blocked they will be resolved.

I recommend to include the tables in /etc/pf.anchors/org.vpnonly.pf.rules

```
...
# Ports
allowed_vpn_ports = "{ 1:65535 }"

# Table with allowed IPs
table <allowed_vpn_ips> const { us1.vpnprovider.com, us2.vpnprovider.com, uk.vpnprovider.com }
table <allowed_dns_ips> const { 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 }

# Block all outgoing packets
block out all
...
```

Test this with `sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf`.

Comment: could you share the full config?

Comment: @jakethedog The full config file can be found in the linked question & answer: [pfctl config to only allow OpenVPN connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259219/93229)